# Treat Warnings as Errors on TFS level VS2017

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I have been struggling with this for a while. I have searched and tried different things but it does not work, so I am posting this here.

I want to treat warnings as errors when building on TFS level and this option has not been working.

I have done it like suggested on other posts: I have tried:
/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true
and
/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"

[Enabling TreatWarningsAsErrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCthg.png)

However, that as been unsuccessful as when building I have the following result:
The warning is not treated as error on TFS build.

[Warning About Unused int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOj78.png)

The build is successful As the image below shows and there are no errors.

[No errors in build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbl1A.png)

Can anyone help me with insight on this about how to do it?

Update:
Obs: I do know the option to set TreatWarningAsErrors on the properties of the project when using VS2017 and that works, as warning are treated as errors there, but that does not work for TFS.

[TreatWarningAsError on VS2017 project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvm0c.png)

[Warning becomes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngMBT.png)

I have enabled treat warnings as errors in VS2017, under project properties, for both Debug and Release.

[Build on TFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De069.png)

Comment: Have you set warnings as errors for all build configurations, it could be that you have set it for debug (hence seeing the issue in VS), but not on release which is probably what you are building in TFS?

Comment: I have changed in VS2017 in the, project properties section, for both Debug and Release to enable all warnings as errors. It works while using VS2017. When I push it to TFS and build it there however, they are still treated as warnings.Anyone has any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested at my side, the argument `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"` works for me:

Note that if you have enabled the `Treat Warnings As Errors`in VS (set to `ALL` or `Specific Warnings`) for the project, then you don't need to add the argument `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"` anymore.

So, you can try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Enable the option (Set to `All`), then **check in changes**, then build
  again.
- Disable the option (set to `None`, just keep it as default), clean
  caches for your client server, then create a new
  build definition, add the argument `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"`
  in build step. Queue a build to check if that works for you.

---

**UPDATE:**

As Kevin mentioned in below comment, the problem is that `SonarQube` seems to be interfering somehow.... Just created a new build definition identical to the first one but **without SonarQube Analysis** and the warnings became errors in the build of the solution.

[image]

Comment: I have done all the steps but still no success. There are two things you mentioned about cleaning caches: I cleaned the cache from client TFS by deleting the folder from this path: C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation. I read it could cause problems. Is that what you mean by "clean caches from AppTier and client server?

Comment: @KevinWrightII Yes, it's the client caches, it will not cause any problems, the caches files will be generated again once you connected to TFS next time. As you can see from the screenshot above, everything works at my side. What 's the exactly version of TFS 2017 do you use? update1 or the latest update3? Try to upgrade to update3 if not yet. Also try to install a new agent, make sure you have installed the Vistual Studio on Agent machine, then try it again.

Comment: I have found the problem. I created a new build definition identical to the first one but without SonarQube Analysis and the warnings became errors in the build of the solution. SonarQube seems to be interfering somehow...

Comment: Thanks for help. I will accept it as answer. Summarizing, SonarQube does not allow the build to fail due to warnings. And, as the answer above states, Build quality Check extension can be used to fail builds due to warnings.

Answer (score 0):

We use a TFS Build Extension for that, [Build Quality Checks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks). Setting the build to fail above a threshold of 0 will fail the build on any compiler warnings:

[image]

Comment: So that means that is not possible without it? I was wondering if I could target a specific project on MsBuild Arguments (shown in the Enabling TreatWarningsAsErrors screenshot). That is because i think maybe they are targeting the solution but not the project with /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true.