# VSTS Build - fail on code analysis warnings

Tags: azure-devops, code-analysis, azure-pipelines

My project uses VSTS Git repository and is being integrated with VSTS Build.

Is there a way to fail the VSTS Build on code analysis warnings? All documentation I found seems to be related to TFVC only.

Comment: There's no difference between Git and TFVC once the source code is downloaded. What specific problem are you having getting code analysis to fail? This is an issue of MSBuild/FxCop, not Git vs TFVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Daniel said, the build steps should be the same once the source code is downloaded from Git or TFVC repository.

So, to fail the build on code analysis warnings, you just need to add below argument in build step:

`/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"`

Besides, you can also use the [Build Quality Checks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks) extension to fail builds due to warnings.

Refer to this thread for details : [Treat Warnings as Errors on TFS level VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963089/treat-warnings-as-errors-on-tfs-level-vs2017/46969682#46969682)